# Error in loading packages RcmrdMisc and tidyverse in R

Tags: r, package, tidyverse

I am having trouble with loading some packages in the R environment.
The following error message pops up for package `RcmdrMisc`

```
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: carData
Loading required package: sandwich
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcmdrMisc’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'checkmate', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package ‘backports’ does not have a namespace
```

Also, I am getting a similar error for package `tidyverse`

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'broom', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package ‘backports’ does not have a namespace
```

I have tried uninstalling the packages and reinstalling them. But the error persists.

I have installed dependencies for the respective packages.
I have downloaded the latest available updates for both `R` and `RStudio`, but to no avail.
What am I doing wrong? Is there any fix for this issue?

Comment: Can you run `library(backports)`? If that works, what version shows up when you run `sessionInfo()`? WHat OS are you using? And what exact version of R are you running? What are you running to install these packages?

Comment: I have tried `library(backports)` ```Error in library(backports) : 
  ‘backports’ is not a valid installed package```. I am on windows 10, with R version 4.0.2. I am using `install.packages(, dependencies = TRUE)` to install the packages. PS. the packages stopped working just out of the blue. They worked in the afternoon, and stopped in the evening. This has now happened twice. Previously uninstalling and re installing worked, but not this time.

Comment: Do you have RTools installed? So what happens when you run `install.packages("backports")`?

Comment: Yes, `RTools` is installed (version 4.0). Backports can be installed via the method mentioned, but after that `library(backports)` returns the message **"this is not a valid install"**.